# Insert blank row in every row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result like this:

```
name
Sally
Dan
Andy
Jackson
```

I used this query:

```
SELECT name from NAMEINFO where nNameIndex<5
```

and I want to get result like this:

```
name
Sally
(blank)
Dan
(blank)
Andy
(blank)
Jackson
(blank)
```

I tried query like this:

```
select name
from (
  select top 100 percent *
  from (
    SELECT nNameIndex, name
    FROM NAMEINFO 
    union all
    select nNameIndex, ''
    from NAMEINFO 
  ) as t
  order by 1
) as r
```

but result is:

```
name
Sally
Dan
Andy
Jackson
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
```

I want to insert blank row into every row in my SQL result.
Where should I change my code to get wanted result?

Comment: You would normally do this in your application - is it essential to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 3):

```
select name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) pos from NAMEINFO where nNameIndex < 5
union all
select '', ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) from NAMEINFO where nNameIndex < 5
order by pos, name desc
```

but really you should not do this in your database but in the consuming application.

Answer (score 3):

In your initial query, you almost have it:

```
  select name
  from (
    SELECT nNameIndex, name
    FROM NAMEINFO 
    union all
    select nNameIndex, ''
    from NAMEINFO 
  ) as t
  order by nNameIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try ROW_NUMBER() to achieve the results.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(name varchar(50))

insert into @table
values 
('Sally')
,('Dan')
,('Andy')
,('Jackson');


SELECT name
from
(
select name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as rnk from @table
union all
SELECT '',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) as rnk  from @table
) as t
order by rnk,name desc
```

```
+---------+
|  name   |
+---------+
| Andy    |
|         |
| Dan     |
|         |
| Jackson |
|         |
| Sally   |
|         |
+---------+
```